# How to deploy AWS CDK app multiple times?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Is it possible to deploy a CDK app to the same account multiple times? I want to run `synth` once and the run `cdk deploy` against that synthesised template multiple times.

I can see that the recent [1.28.0 release](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/releases/tag/v1.28.0) of the CDK allows for passing CloudFormation parameters into the `deploy command` (via [#1237](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1237)).  This means I can parameterize the contents of a stack, but I don't know how to change the name/id of the app itself.

For example, here is a simple app:

```
public class ExampleApp {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        App app = new App();

        new ExampleStack(app, "ExampleStack");

        app.synth();
    }
}
```

and here is a simple do-nothing stack:

```
public class ExampleStack extends Stack {

    public ExampleStack(final Construct scope, final String id) {
        this(scope, id, null);
    }

    public ExampleStack(final Construct scope, final String id, final StackProps props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        CfnParameter someVar = CfnParameter.Builder.create(this, "SomeVar")
                .description("Some variable that can be passed in at deploy-time.")
                .type("String")
                .build();

        // rest of stack here
    }
}
```

I can run `cdk synth` and output the template somewhere, then run

```
cdk --app path/to/cdk.out deploy ExampleStack --parameters "ExampleStack:SomeVar=SomeValue"
```

and the parameter will be passed into the stack at deploy-time.

However, I don't see how to deploy the app multiple times with different names (or ids). Is this possible?

The background to why I want to do this, NOT run `synth` multiple times, is because for compliance reasons, I need a single artifact - the `cdk.out` directory - and then deploy that multiple times. To that end, I can't use answers based around multiple runs of `synth`.

Comment: Have you tried adding a loop? `for (String name : myListOfNames) new ExampleStack(app, name);`

Comment: Or just constructing it twice with different ids? (Without a necessarily using a loop)

Comment: No, unfortunately that would still define the stacks at `synth` time, not `deploy` time. At the time of running `synth`, I do not know how many instances of the stack I will require.

Comment: Oh sorry. I misunderstood about running deploy multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

1. You need to make your stack name a parameter passed in from the command line
2. remove the app paramter from your cdk.json and specify the app parameter on the command line passing in the "prefix" parameter

*Any resources in your stack with with service level names or IDs need to also be modified, for example two stacks can't create a secret with the same name*

In my solution I derived from the StackProps object to add a "PrefixName" property to the stack and the prefix can be used within my stack to influence the naming or resources.

My program.cs looks as follows:

```
using Amazon.CDK;

namespace DevconnectListener
{
    sealed class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = new App();
            var props = new DevConnectStackProps()
            {
                PrefixName = args[0],
                StackName = args[0]  + "-DevconnectListenerStack"
            };

            var s = new DevconnectListenerStack(app, "DevconnectListenerStack", props);
            

            app.Synth();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my custom DevConnectStackProps class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Amazon.CDK;
using Amazon.CDK.AWS.DynamoDB;
using Amazon.CDK.AWS.Lambda;

namespace DevconnectListener
{

    public class DevConnectStackProps : StackProps, IStackProps
    {
        public DevConnectStackProps()
        {

        }
        public string PrefixName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My cdk.json look like this, removed the app property:

```
{
  "context": {
    "@aws-cdk/core:enableStackNameDuplicates": "true",
    "aws-cdk:enableDiffNoFail": "true",
    "@aws-cdk/core:stackRelativeExports": "true"
  }
}
```

Then there is a CMD file named deploy-dev.cmd (which contains the aws profile i want to use and the dev prefix parameter:

```
cdk deploy --app "dotnet run -p src/DevconnectListener/DevconnectListener.csproj dev" --profile dev_aws_profile
```

If you run this again with a different prefix, you'll see a new stack in the CloudFormation console.